# Execute code synchronously in node.js controller

Tags: javascript, node.js

Just started with Node.js few weeks ago, i'm trying to execute this code synchronously  located in my controller

> Quest.js

```
async function create(req, res, next) {
    
      const formValue = req.body['form'];
      let quest;
      const riddles = [];
    
      try {
        //get current user who created this Quest
        await User.findOne({_id: req.body.id})
          .then(currentUser => {
    
            /*-------------------------------START QUEST CREATION-------------------------------*/
            quest = new Quest({
              admin: currentUser,
              hunter: new User,
              launchDate: formValue.launchDate,
              penaltyTime: formValue.penaltyTime,
            });
            /*-------------------------------END QUEST CREATION-------------------------------*/
    
            /*-------------------------------START RIDDLES CREATION-------------------------------*/
            let riddle;
            console.log('step1');
            //Riddles instantiation
            for (const [key, participantEmail] of Object.entries(formValue.participantsEmail)) {
    
              if (formValue.riddle.text == "") {
                throw ('errorMsg:IncorrectRiddleText/code:422/field:riddleText');
              }
              if (formValue.riddle.answer == "") {
                throw ('errorMsg:IncorrectRiddleAnswer/code:422/field:riddleAnswer');
              }
    
              //if its the first riddle => i.e : the one created by the current user
              if (`${key}` == 0) {
                riddle = new Riddle({
                  quest: quest,
                  author: currentUser,
                  authorEmail: currentUser.email,
                  text: formValue.riddle.text,
                  answer: formValue.riddle.answer,
                  status: true,
                  nextRiddle: null
                });
              }
              //if it's a waiting riddle
              else {
                if (!validator.validateEmail(participantEmail.participantEmail)) {
                  throw ('errorMsg:IncorrectEmail/code:422/field:participantEmail');
                }
                if (participantEmail.participantEmail)
                  riddle = new Riddle({
                    quest: quest,
                    authorEmail: `${participantEmail.participantEmail}`,
                    nextRiddle: null
                  });
                //assign last created riddle to the one before to make the good order
                riddles[`${key}` - 1].nextRiddle = riddle;
              }
              //create riddle list for Quest
              riddles.push(riddle);
            }
    
            /*-------------------------------END RIDDLES CREATION-------------------------------*/
    
            /*-------------------------------START USER MANAGEMENT-------------------------------*/
            //create a User for the hunter or if he already have an account => link it to the new Quest
            User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail})
              .then(hunterUser => {
                  console.log('step2');
                  if (hunterUser == null) {//if userHunter doesn't exist yet => create it
                    userHelper.createUser(
                      formValue.hunterFirstName,
                      formValue.hunterLastName,
                      formValue.hunterFirstName + formValue.hunterLastName.slice(-1),
                      formValue.hunterEmail,
                      Text.generateRandomPassword()
                    ).then((createdUser) => {
                      console.log('step3');
                      hunterUser = createdUser;
    
                    }).catch(error => {
                      console.log('error1')
                        error = Text.parseErrorToObject(error)
                        return res.status(parseInt(error.code.toString())).json(error);
                      }
                    );
                  }
                  console.log('step4');
                  questHelper.saveQuest(quest, riddles, hunterUser)
                    .then(() => {
                      console.log('step5');
                      return res.status(200).json({'msg': 'Quest created'})
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      console.log('error2')
                        error = Text.parseErrorToObject(error)
                        return res.status(parseInt(error.code.toString())).json(error);
                      }
                    );
                }
              ).then().catch(error => {
              throw (Text.parseErrorToObject(error));
            })
    
            /*-------------------------------END USER MANAGEMENT-------------------------------*/
    
          })
          .catch(error => {
              throw (Text.parseErrorToObject(error));
            }
          );
    
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error3')
        return res.status(parseInt(e.code.toString())).json(e);
      }
    };
```

But when i execute this if i display the logs ihave this :

```
step1
step2
step4
step3
```

I know why it's doing this, du to the fact that JS is asynchronous multi-thtreading.
But i can't figure out how to execute this block (step4) :

```
questHelper.saveQuest(quest, riddles, hunterUser)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('step5');
                  return res.status(200).json({'msg': 'Quest created'})
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log('error2')
                    error = Text.parseErrorToObject(error)
                    return res.status(parseInt(error.code.toString())).json(error);
                  }
                );
```

When the previous block is over. That mean, when `hunterUser = createdUser;` is executed

EDIT :

Thanks to all answers, i have cleaned my code and went out of all the then/catch block.
It lost a lot of weight :p and so much readable.
The error management is so much easier this way too

```
async function create(req, res, next) {

  const formValue = req.body['form'];
  const riddles = [];

  try {
    //get current user who created this Quest
    const currentUser = await User.findOne({_id: req.body.id});

    /*-------------------------------START QUEST CREATION-------------------------------*/
    let quest = await new Quest({
      admin: currentUser,
      hunter: new User,
      launchDate: formValue.launchDate,
      penaltyTime: formValue.penaltyTime,
    });
    /*-------------------------------END QUEST CREATION-------------------------------*/

    /*-------------------------------START RIDDLES CREATION-------------------------------*/
    let riddle;
    //Riddles instantiation
    for (const [key, participantEmail] of Object.entries(formValue.participantsEmail)) {

      if (formValue.riddle.text == "") {
        throw ('errorMsg:IncorrectRiddleText/code:422/field:riddleText');
      }
      if (formValue.riddle.answer == "") {
        throw ('errorMsg:IncorrectRiddleAnswer/code:422/field:riddleAnswer');
      }

      //if its the first riddle => i.e : the one created by the current user
      if (`${key}` == 0) {
        riddle = new Riddle({
          quest: quest,
          author: currentUser,
          authorEmail: currentUser.email,
          text: formValue.riddle.text,
          answer: formValue.riddle.answer,
          status: true,
          nextRiddle: null
        });
      }
      //if it's a waiting riddle
      else {
        if (!validator.validateEmail(participantEmail.participantEmail)) {
          throw ('errorMsg:IncorrectEmail/code:422/field:participantEmail');
        }
        if (participantEmail.participantEmail)
          riddle = new Riddle({
            quest: quest,
            authorEmail: `${participantEmail.participantEmail}`,
            nextRiddle: null
          });
        //assign last created riddle to the one before to make the good order
        riddles[`${key}` - 1].nextRiddle = riddle;
      }
      //create riddle list for Quest
      riddles.push(riddle);
    }
    /*-------------------------------END RIDDLES CREATION-------------------------------*/

    /*-------------------------------START USER MANAGEMENT-------------------------------*/
    //create a User for the hunter or if he already have an account => link it to the new Quest
    let hunterUser = await User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail});
    if (hunterUser == null) {//if userHunter doesn't exist yet => create it
      hunterUser = await userHelper.createUser(
        formValue.hunterFirstName,
        formValue.hunterLastName,
        formValue.hunterFirstName + formValue.hunterLastName.slice(-1),//TODO add a unique ID
        formValue.hunterEmail,
        Text.generateRandomPassword()
      )
    }
    await questHelper.saveQuest(quest, riddles, hunterUser)
    return res.status(200).json({'msg': 'Quest created'})


    /*-------------------------------END USER MANAGEMENT-------------------------------*/

  } catch (error) {
    error = Text.parseErrorToObject(error);
    return res.status(parseInt(error.code.toString())).json(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: *"when `hunterUser = createdUser;` is executed"* - That's what the callback function you're using is for.  See the blank line right after that line of code?  Whatever you want to happen after that line of code would go right there, within that overall `.then()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearly you already understand how "async" and "await" work. Now it's just about remembering to apply them for every network I/O operation.

And so if you change

```js
await User.findOne({_id: req.body.id})
          .then(currentUser => {
```

to

```js
await User.findOne({_id: req.body.id})
          .then(async currentUser => {
```

then suddenly you'll be able to use `await` inside that block.

Now you need to change

```js
User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail})
              .then(hunterUser => {
```

to

```js
await User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail})
              .then(hunterUser => {
```

your current solution basically says "find user and once you're done do this and that..." and then you don't actually wait until the user is found, so that basically has to be fixed.

Better yet, you could drop all of the '.then()' and '.catch' blocks since they can be easily replaced with the "async/await" syntax.

So instead of writing

```js
await User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail})
              .then(hunterUser => { ...someLogic })
```

in a more modern way you could write

```js
const hunerUser = await User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail});
//...someLogic
```

Comment: Omg thanks for this , the async keyword changed my life :p 

i'm now going to try to clean my code with the help of all the other answers and yours. Especially for the then and catch block that are clearly make the code hard to read :s

Comment: yeah. async/await were introduced in Node v7, but ".then()" has never really been deprecated like it should have been and so, newcomers often find it confusing... JS is slowly becoming the new C++ where you still have features from 20 years ago that you shouldn't use, but as a beginner you don't know you shouldn't use them...

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using `await` and `.then()` at the same line of code, which won't produce any value.
I'd suggest using the ES6 `async` `await` keywords alone which will make your different parts of code execeute after each promise has been resolved.

Step 4 should look something like this:

```
try {
    const result = await questHelper.saveQuest(quest, riddles, hunterUser);
    console.log('step5');
    return res.status(200).json({'msg': 'Quest created'})
}
catch (error) {
    console.log('error2')
    error = Text.parseErrorToObject(error)
    return res.status(parseInt(error.code.toString())).json(error);
}
```

Comment: There is no point in having `.then` in the first place, it could be all done with `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Any logic that should happen after the asynchronous operation should be moved to its callback function.  Currently you have this structure:

```
User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail})
  .then(hunterUser => {
    //...
    userHelper.createUser(/*...*/)
      .then((createdUser) => {
        //...
        // YOU WANT TO DO SOMETHING HERE
      });
      // THIS IS THE CODE YOU WANT DO EXECUTE ABOVE
  });
```

If you want that later block of code to be executed in response to the completion of the `userHelper.createUser` operation, move it to the callback where you respond to the result of that operation:

```
User.findOne({email: formValue.hunterEmail})
  .then(hunterUser => {
    //...
    userHelper.createUser(/*...*/)
      .then((createdUser) => {
        //...
        // THIS IS THE CODE YOU WANT DO EXECUTE
      });
  });
```

Overall it seems you're getting confused by a large and complex set of nested callbacks.  The [`async` and `await` syntax](https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await) for `Promises` is meant to address that and make the syntax more clear.  If these asynchronous operations return `Promises` then you're definitely encouraged to make use of that syntax instead of all of these `.then()` callbacks.

But even with the `.then()` syntax, all you need to do is identify your blocks of code and where they belong.  Either something should execute immediately (after the `.then()`), or it should execute in response to an asynchronous operation (inside the `.then()`.